# Flexbox not working on iPad and Safari

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm using flexbox on a website and it crashes on iPad Air, iPad 3 and Safari PC.

The design and the code is similar to this codepen.
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xwJzEg/

```
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
```

This is how it looks on those devices where the problem occurs:[image]

Any advice how to workaround this?

Answer (score 17):

You may want to consider Safari browser support for flexbox.

Although Safari 9 supports all standard flex properties, with Safari 8 and older you'll need to use vendor prefixes.

Make this adjustment to your code:

```
.container {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: -webkit-flex; /* NEW */
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap; /* NEW */
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    font-family: "Open Sans";
}
```

See flexbox browser support here: http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox

Consider using [Autoprefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/).

See flexbox code samples with prefixes: [The Ultimate Flexbox Cheat Sheet](http://www.sketchingwithcss.com/samplechapter/cheatsheet.html)

Comment: My biggest problems are Ipad 3 and Ipad Air on latest browsers (Chrome and Safari)

Comment: What exactly is happening? Can you post an image of the problem or more details?

Comment: Posted screenshot in the question.

Comment: I just tested your code on my iPad. Works fine with prefixes added. See my revised answer.

Comment: I'm having an iPad3 and an iPad Air on my desk and none of them works.... sadly...  I still can't find the problem. I also tried that codepen with the improvements on those ipads and it shows a white screen.....................

Comment: Which browser and version are you using?

Comment: latest chrome and safari

Comment: On latest Chrome and Safari on my iOS devices the layout works. Not sure how else I can help you, unless you want to provide exact Chrome and Safari and device version and model #'s.

Comment: Late comment but it mostly depends on the iOS version, not the Safari version.

Answer (score 7):

I used [Autoprefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/) as suggested in the answers.

I use gulp to handle this when I write SASS. Here is a [guide](https://www.sitepoint.com/simple-gulpy-workflow-sass/).

Answers here are suggesting to use a prefixed property before the non prefixed one. I agree with a small correction.

```
.container {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    display: flex;   
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Ideally, you need to list all of the prefixed properties before you start using the non prefixed ones. @Michael_B answer is not perfect in my opinion.

I hope people will find this useful.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried setting flex values for the first-child and last-child li elements? I've found that iPads can get confused if none of the flex-items in a flex-container have a flex value. For example:

```
.container li:first-child {
    flex:1; 
    -webkit-box-flex:1; 
    -webkit-flex:1;
}
.container li:nth-child(4) {
    flex:1; 
    -webkit-box-flex:1; 
    -webkit-flex:1;
}
```